# Is F# ResizeArray sortBy stable?

Tags: sorting, f#

Does the function ResizeArray.sortBy do a stable sort, in the sense that it does not change the order of elements which have the same value for the key function?

And if not, how to write a stable sort in F#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Seq.sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353483.aspx) is stable.

Answer (score 10):

The answer to your question is `unstable`.

First `ResizeArray.sortBy` is implemented as:

```
module ResizeArray =
    let sortBy f (arr: ResizeArray<'T>) = arr.Sort (System.Comparison(fun x y -> compare (f x) (f y)))
```

And `ResizeArray` is an alias for .Net List collection:

```
type ResizeArray<'T> = System.Collections.Generic.List<'T> // alias
```

Now let's look at the [List documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx):

> This method uses Array.Sort, which
>   uses the QuickSort algorithm. This
>   implementation performs an unstable
>   sort; that is, if two elements are
>   equal, their order might not be
>   preserved. In contrast, a stable sort
>   preserves the order of elements that
>   are equal.

So unstable. If you want a stable sort, you can implement merge sort or a careful quick sort. However the stable version quick sort is less efficient.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good theoretical answer. It is easier to use the available Seq.sortBy as per Brian's answer.